# Move cursor multiple lines in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I'm looking for a keybinding that will move the cursor x number of lines up or down in Atom, a la Vim.

I've looked around but can only find `cmd+up` and `cmd+down`, which move the cursor to the top or bottom of the file respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`go-to-line`](https://atom.io/packages/go-to-line) package. Default keyboard shortcut is <kbd>CTRL+G</kbd>. Install it via the terminal with

```
$ apm install go-to-line
```

or download it through Settings.